# App that makes another app unavaible after x clicks for x period of time

Tags: android, iphone

I want to make an app that can Hide, lock or some kind of block any other app.
Lets say you've download an App (A) that registres how many times you have clicked on another App (B).In App (A) you can set a limit on how many times you can click/use app (B), before it's blocked. When you have clicked x times on App (B), it will be hidden, locked or some kind of blocked for use until x time have passed.
Can this be done in some way?

Comment: Impossible unless you build your own custom ROM.  Android security will not allow this.

Comment: On iOS you could make it if you develop both app, but not with any random app. Also the hole logic should be coded in both apps. Also you wil not be able to hide the app, just display some message when you start the restricted app.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answers. Appreciate it a lot :-) Could it be done like this, or is that also impossible? You download App (A). It will put some kind of code on all the other apps, of course you have to accept this. This code will make you able to control the apps from App (A), and that way make it work?

Comment: No, not unless the other apps are already written to allow this.